# can we use two wordpress portal in one domain ?

Tags: php, wordpress

Can we use WordPress in another word press like this WordPress/testWordPress ?
So how is it possible please explain me in brief. Both word press database is different or single ?

Comment: The installation instructions for WordPress explain that. http://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_Multiple_Blogs

Answer (score 2):

Yes, since wordpress 3.0, it is possible to use the mutlisite feature to create multiple wordpress sites on one domain.

Just google...

Checkout these sites:

1. http://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_Multiple_Blogs
2. http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network